Isomorphism for localized module
I'm currently trying to figure out the following: Let $A$ be a ring and $S\subset A$ a multiplicatively closed set. Then for any $A$-module $M$ there is a canonical isomorphism $f:S^{-1}A\otimes M\rightarrow S^{-1}M;\;[\frac{a}{s}]\otimes m\mapsto [\frac{am}{s}]$.
So first i checked that this map is well-defined and also surjective. But now I am struggling to prove that the map is injective. I tried to consider the kernel of the map, but i cant prove that the kernel is trivial.
Maybe I'm having a wrong perception of $[0]\in S^{-1}A\otimes M$, but for example consider $[\frac{a}{s}]\otimes m$ with $0\neq a\in$ Ann($m$), then $f([\frac{a}{s}]\otimes m)=0$. For $f$ to be an isomorphism, $[\frac{a}{s}]\otimes m= [0]\in S^{-1}A\otimes M$. But I dont see why this is the case.
Maybe someone can help me out?

Don't forget that not every element in the tensor product is a simple tensor, but a finite sum of such. So if you want to check the kernel is trivial, you have to take a sum of simple tensors. But I suggest a different approach: instead of trying to show injectivity, better try to define the inverse map. This is often easier to do when working with a tensor product. In this case, the map is very natural.

Duplicate question. Please use site search.
